# Why Clang compiler complains although all includes are presented

Tags: c, makefile, clang

I'm trying to work through [XDP tutorial](https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial) and having issue with samples compilation. Why clang complains regarding includes that are already done?

Example:

```
common_params.c:105:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strncpy’
common_params.c:105:4: note: include ‘<string.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘strncpy’
common_params.c:110:6: error: ‘errno’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  110 |      errno, strerror(errno));
      |      ^~~~~
common_params.c:15:1: note: ‘errno’ is defined in header ‘<errno.h>’; did you forget to ‘#include <errno.h>’?
   14 | #include "common_params.h"
  +++ |+#include <errno.h>
```

Cheching common_params.c shoes it already have string.h and errno.h included:

```
# head ../common/common_params.c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Files are presented in the box:

```
# ls -l /usr/include/errno.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23 Jun  6 18:36 /usr/include/errno.h
# ls -l /usr/include/string.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 238 Jun  6 18:36 /usr/include/string.h

# cat /usr/include/errno.h
#include <asm/errno.h>
# cat /usr/include/asm/errno.h
#include <asm-generic/errno.h>
# head /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 WITH Linux-syscall-note */
#ifndef _ASM_GENERIC_ERRNO_H
#define _ASM_GENERIC_ERRNO_H

#include <asm-generic/errno-base.h>

#define EDEADLK     35  /* Resource deadlock would occur */
#define ENAMETOOLONG    36  /* File name too long */
#define ENOLCK      37  /* No record locks available */
```

Comment: It seems as if Clang does not have the option `-E` that GCC has to output the preprocessed source. However, there might be a similar one. You could use it to investigate this in more detail. -- I suspect some preprocessor definition to hide the declarations, or some preprocessor conditional, or something other we don't see. You might want to [edit] your question and **add** a [mre], with emphasis on "complete".

Comment: @thebusybee: Clang has `-E`.

Comment: I have no idea what `# head ....` means; is this a typo or some kind of special clang feature?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, good to know! I just peeked quickly in Clang's on-line manual and did not find it.